# Show that if $k>1$, then $-1+6\csc(\frac{2\pi}{kx})\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{3kx})<-k+6k\csc(\frac{2\pi}{x})\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{3x})$

Tags: inequality

I was wondering how to show that for $k>1$ ($k\in\mathbb{R}$) and $x>10$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}$) the following inequality holds.

$-1+6\csc(\frac{2\pi}{kx})\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{3kx})<-k+6k\csc(\frac{2\pi}{x})\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{3x})$

Note that 
any hint will be appreciated. This can be verified graphically, moreover the inequality turns equality if $k=1$ or $k=-1$ which is very clear (by the way I am not sure these are the only two values which makes two sides are identical) if that's the case, then two function never meet again which implies one of them always greater.

Comment: I think that the inequality holds for $k > 1$ and $x > 2$. One may use derivative to prove it.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Could you clarify more please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof is quite complicated. I will post it later.

Answer (score 1):

*Problem*: Let $k > 1$ and $x > 2$ be two real numbers. Prove that
$$-1 + 6\csc\tfrac{2\pi}{kx}\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{3} + \tfrac{2\pi}{3kx})
< -k + 6k\csc\tfrac{2\pi}{x}\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{3} + \tfrac{2\pi}{3x}).$$

**Proof**: First, we give the following auxiliary result (the proof is given later):

*Fact 1*: Let $g(u) = u\left(-1 + 6\csc (3u) \sin(\tfrac{\pi}{3} + u)\right)$. Then $g'(u) > 0$ on $(0, \frac{\pi}{3})$.

Let us proceed. Let $u_1 = \frac{2\pi}{3kx}$ and $u_2 = \frac{2\pi}{3x}$. Then $0 < u_1 < u_2 < \frac{\pi}{3}$.
From Fact 1, we have $g(u_1) < g(u_2)$ and thus $\frac{1}{u_1} g(u_1) < \frac{1}{u_1} g(u_2)$ which is exactly the desired inequality. We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*: Denote $c = \cos u$ and $s = \sin u$. We have
$$g'(u) = \frac{h_1(u) - h_2(u)}{s^2(4c^2-1)^2}$$
where
\begin{align}
h_1(u) &= 16 c^6+12 c^3s \sqrt{3} + (12 u \sqrt{3} + 24) c^2 + 24 u c s+3 u \sqrt{3},\\
h_2(u) &= (24u\sqrt{3}+36)c^4+24usc^3+3cs\sqrt{3} + 4.
\end{align}
Since $\sin u \ge u - \frac{u^3}{3}$ and $\cos u \ge 1 - \frac{u^2}{2}$ for $u\in (0, \frac{\pi}{3})$,
by denoting $s_1 = u - \frac{u^3}{3}$ and $c_1 = 1 - \frac{u^2}{2}$, we have for $u\in (0, \frac{\pi}{3})$,
$$h_1(u) \ge 16 c_1^6+12 c_1^3s_1 \sqrt{3} + (12 u \sqrt{3} + 24) c_1^2 + 24 u c_1 s_1+3 u \sqrt{3} \triangleq H_1(u).$$
Since $\sin u \le u$ and $\cos u \le 1 - \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^4}{24}$ for $u\in (0, \frac{\pi}{3})$,
by denoting $s_2 = u$ and $c_2 = 1 - \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^4}{24}$, we have for $u\in (0, \frac{\pi}{3})$,
$$h_2(u) \le (24u\sqrt{3}+36)c_2^4+24us_2c_2^3+3c_2s_2\sqrt{3} + 4 \triangleq H_2(u).$$
Thus, we have for $u\in (0, \frac{\pi}{3})$,
$$g'(u) \ge \frac{H_1(u) - H_2(u)}{s^2(4c^2-1)^2} = \frac{u^{12}F_1(u) + u^8 F_2(u) + 3456F_3(u)}{27648s^2(4c^2-1)^2}$$
where
\begin{align}
F_1(u) &= -2\sqrt{3}\, u^5 - 3u^4 + 96\sqrt{3}\, u^3 + 96u^2 - 1920\sqrt{3}\, u  + 5760,\\
F_2(u) &= 20736\sqrt{3}\, u^3 - 76032u^2 - 117504\sqrt{3}\, u + 383616,\\
F_3(u) &= 108\sqrt{3}\, u^4 - 240u^3 - 177\sqrt{3}\, u^2  + 176u + 124\sqrt{3}.
\end{align}
We have for $u\in (0, \frac{\pi}{3})$,
$$F_1(u) \ge -2\sqrt{3}\, (\tfrac{\pi}{3})^5 - 3(\tfrac{\pi}{3})^4 - 1920\sqrt{3}\, (\tfrac{\pi}{3}) + 5760 > 0$$
and
$$F_2(u) \ge  - 76032(\tfrac{\pi}{3})^2 - 117504\sqrt{3}\, (\tfrac{\pi}{3}) + 383616 > 0.$$
From Descartes' sign rule, since there are two sign changes, $F_3(u) = 0$ has at most two positive real solutions.
Note also that $F_3(0) > 0$, $F_3(\frac{\pi}{3}) > 0$, $F_3(\frac{3}{2}) < 0$ and $F_3(2) > 0$.
We conclude that $F_3(u) > 0$ for $u\in (0, \frac{\pi}{3})$. 
Thus, $g'(u) > 0$ for $u\in (0, \frac{\pi}{3})$. We are done.

Comment: I could not think this way to be honest, I really appreciate the time you spent for typing for the long proof, and I am sorry for any inconvenience. I am happy to know that there exist a way to prove it even it is quite long. We are manipulating the Taylor expansion  by taking enough term to to change the ign of the inequality ( I think) . It seems the inequality even true when x>2 I was originally thinking x>10. Thanks a lot again. I will read it again the details.

Comment: Well, if you use Computer Algebra System (CAS) such as Maple, Matlab, Mathematica, etc. to do the symbol computing, it is easy.